# c# multiple threads waiting for a ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading, manualresetevent

I'm messing around with multithreading and making some sort of task engine. The idea is that the engine can have a configurable amount of threads waiting and when a new task arrives the first free thread picks it up and executes it.

The problem is that something 2 threads pickup the same task somehow. I looked it through and I think that this code should work but obviously it doesn't. If I add the 10ms sleep where it is now commented out it works, but I'm not sure I understand why. It looks like the .Reset() function returns before it actually resets the event?

Can somebody explain? Is there a better way to let only a single thread continue when there are multiple waiting?

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskTest
{
    public class Engine
    {
        private ManualResetEvent taskEvent;
        private ConcurrentQueue<Task> tasks;
        private bool running;
        private List<Thread> threads;
        private int threadAmount;
        private int threadsBusy = 0;

        public Engine(int amountOfThreads)
        {
            taskEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            tasks = new ConcurrentQueue<Task>();
            threads = new List<Thread>();

            threadAmount = amountOfThreads;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            running = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < threadAmount; i++)
            {
                var thread = new Thread(Process);
                thread.Name = "Thread " + i;
                threads.Add(thread);
                thread.Start();
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            running = false;
            taskEvent.Set();
            threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());
        }

        private void Process()
        {
            while (running)
            {
                lock (taskEvent)
                {
                    // Lock it so only a single thread is waiting on the event at the same time
                    taskEvent.WaitOne();
                    taskEvent.Reset();
                    //Thread.Sleep(10);
                }

                if (!running)
                {
                    taskEvent.Set();
                    return;
                }

                threadsBusy += 1;
                if (threadsBusy > 1)
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed");

                Task task;
                if (tasks.TryDequeue(out task))
                    task.Execute();

                threadsBusy -= 1;
            }
        }

        public void Enqueue(Task t)
        {
            tasks.Enqueue(t);
            taskEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT
Rest of the code:

```
namespace TaskTest
{
    public class Start
    {
        public static void Main(params string[] args)
        {
            var engine = new Engine(4);
            engine.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Read();
                engine.Enqueue(new Task());
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace TaskTest
{
    public class Task
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want lock (obj) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: This does not directly answer your question, but you should use a BlockingCollection instead. It's already doing what you're trying to do, except that it works

Comment: How would that be any different from using a ConcurrentQueue?

Comment: Also, there's an obvious race condition if you call `Enqueue` twice: the first thread resumes ans increments `threadsBusy` and starts executing the work. The second thread resumes too (since the first one exited the lock) and increments `threadsBusy` too => `threadsBusy` is now equal to 2

Comment: `How would that be any different from using a ConcurrentQueue?` The BlockingCollection does all the synchronization for you. Start n threads and have them call `foreach (var task in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())`. At the other hand, call `queue.Enqueue(t)`. Done, you can remove everything else

Comment: I'll look into the BlockingCollection, but for educational purposes I'd still like  more info about why the current solution doesn't work. Regarding your previous comment, I was testing this with calling the Enqueue just 1 time per execution, I understand that if I call it 2 times right after eachother it would have 2 threads busy

Comment: For your current solution, what makes you think that two threads are picking the same task? It shouldn't be possible. `tasks.TryDequeue` on the `ConcurrentQueue` makes sure that it never happens

Comment: What is Task.Execute doing? It is not a known method of the known Task class. Seems to be an extension method

Comment: That's what I thought, which is why I'm confused. Current setup is that it's a console application doing a Console.Read() and an engine.Enqueue(new Task()) so that every time I press enter it enqueues a task. The task is a simple class, only having the execute function and a Console.WriteLine of Thread.CurrentThread.Name. Now sometimes when I press enter it prints Thread 0; Failed; Thread1 on a single enter press..

Comment: @SirRufo The task class is my own class with just a single method. I guess the name might be a bit confusing

Comment: It is when you include the namespace System.Threading.Tasks as you do

Comment: Nothing in what you said allows you to conclude that "two threads are picking up the same task". It's much more likely that two tasks are pushed to the queue. Can we see the part of the code that waits for key presses and does the enqueuing?

Comment: I've updated the question with the rest of the code. Even when I press the enter key like 1 times every 2 seconds after a couple of times i still get the failed message.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can you add a `Console.WriteLine` inside of `Enqueue` to make sure you don't enqueue more tasks than you think?

Comment: Well I found the issue, as you expected when I added the Console.WriteLine in the Enqueue function it showed twice for every enter press. Turns out the Console.Read(); in the main function passed twice when I pressed enter. I swapped it for a Console.ReadLine(); and now it works as expected. Thanks for helping me track down this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `Console.Read()` on a key press, two characters are read from the input. You should use `Console.ReadLine()` instead.

Note that your code can be simplified a lot by using a `BlockingCollection` to handle the synchronization:

```
public class Engine
{
    private BlockingCollection<Task> tasks;
    private List<Thread> threads;
    private int threadAmount;

    public Engine(int amountOfThreads)
    {
        tasks = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
        threads = new List<Thread>();

        threadAmount = amountOfThreads;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < threadAmount; i++)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(Process);
            thread.Name = "Thread " + i;
            threads.Add(thread);
            thread.Start();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        tasks.CompleteAdding();
        threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());
    }

    private void Process()
    {
        foreach (var task in tasks.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            task.Execute();
        }
    }

    public void Enqueue(Task t)
    {
        tasks.Add(t);
    }
}
```